# Homeomorphism from $O(n)/(O(1)\times O(n-1))$ to $S^{n-1}/\tilde{}$

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to find a homeomorphism from $O(n)/(O(1)\times{}O(n-1))$ with $O(1)\times{}O(n-1)$ being matrices with 1 or -1 in the top left and a matrix of $O(n-1)$ at the bottom right to the Sphere where opposite points are identified, so $x\tilde{}(-1)$. I can find a function

$f : O(n) \to S^{n-1}/\tilde{}$

$f(A)=[A*e_1]$

which is continuous if I'm not mistaken. Now the universal property of the quotient space says that $g : O(n)/(O(1)\times{}O(n-1)) \to S^{n-1}/\tilde{}$ is continous as well. However I'm having trouble showing that this is a bijective. If $[A]=[B]$ then the $A*e1=B*e1$ or $A*e1=-B*e1$ but I can't show the other direction which would be necessary to show injectivity as far as I can see.

Once I have bijectivity it needs to be a homeomorphism because $O(n)$ is compact and $S^{n-1}/\tilde{}$ is Hausdorff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $Ae_1=\pm Be_1$, then $B^{-1}A$ fixes $\pm e_1$, hence it is in the subgroup
$
O(1)\times O(n-1)
$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just figured it out myself 10 seconds ago :)